# How to transpose rows and columns in Access 2003?

Tags: ms-access, transpose

How do I transpose rows and columns in Access 2003?  I have a multiple tables that I need to do this on.

(I've reworded my question because feedback tells me it was confusing how I originally stated it.)

Each table has 30 fields and 20 records.
Lets say my fields are Name, Weight, Zip Code, Quality4, Quality5, Quality6 through Quality30 which is favorite movie.
Let's say the records each describe a person.  The people are Alice, Betty, Chuck, Dave, Edward etc through Tommy..

I can easily make a report like this:

```
  >>Alice...120....35055---etc, etc, etc...Jaws  
  Betty....125....35212...etc, etc, etc...StarWars  
  etc  
  etc  
  etc  
  Tommy...200...35213...etc, etc, etc...Adaptation
```

But what I would like to do is transpose those rows and columns so my report displays like this

```
  >>Alice........Betty......etc,etc,etc...Tommy  
  120.........125........etc, etc, etc...200  
  35055.....35212....etc, etc, etc...35213  
  etc   
  etc  
  etc  
  Jaws...StarWars..etc,etc,etc...Adaptation
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just removed the "transaction" tag, there's no transaction involved here ...

Answer (score 2):

Access actually has a transpose verb, crosstab. You'll find good stuff if you search for "crosstab", which is the more common database-y way to say it. Like this [Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304348). The generic database answers usually involve transpose and summarize. If you need a non-summary crosstab, it can be done, but you'll likely need a custom function.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I think I dont understand though.
The Knowledge Base article talks about summarizing but all I want to do is transpose rows-to-columns and columns-to-row.  I dont want to summarize.  Surely this must be something people do !!  Any other ideas?  (I dont have the skills to do a customer function.)  Thanks.

Comment: The Crosstab Wizard will walk you through the whole process.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd response.  But I'm afraid I still just dont get it.  I searched and read about Crosstab and used the Crosstab wizard and I just simply dont see how on earth to transpose stuff -- change all my rows to columns and all my columns to rows.  To rephrase what I am trying to do: I need to display my 30 fields as rows (instead of columns), and my 20 reords as columns (instead of rows).  Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all for your help.
I believe I have discovered the answer, and I put the link to it here in case someone else needs it in the future:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202176
(This works for Access 2003.)

Comment: Which of the two approaches outlined there did you choose?

Answer (score 0):

```
TRANSFORM SUM(Weight)
SELECT "Dummy Data"
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY "Dummy Data"
PIVOT [Name]
```

Does this help?

EDIT: This assumes that names won't repeat.
i.e. There will not be more than 1 record for a given Name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have lots and lots more fields/columns than just Name and Weight, and lots more records/rows. (I have 20+ unique names.)  I just tried to keep my example very simple.  How would I word your query if I had Field1 through Field30 and 20 unique names instead of just fields Weight and Age.  To rephrase, all I am trying to do is transpose, i.e., for my report, turn my 30 columns into 30 rows and turn my 20 rows into 30 columns.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: I mean turn my 20 rows into 20 columns

Comment: Please edit your question to describe your real schema alongwith sample data & expected output that you would like to see. I will try to see, if it can be done. Once you edit the question, post your comments here for me to take notice of it.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I appreciate it.  I have reworded what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in the end I resorted to exporting the table to Excel, do the transpose and then imported it back to Access again.